# Error:(3, 25) object ml is not a member of package org.apache.flink import org.apache.flink.ml.MLUtils in flink using scala

Tags: scala, apache-flink

[Code for executing machine learning model in flink using scala](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCTZV.png)

[Error of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtIN5.png)

can someone please help me solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've added dependency to:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
  <artifactId>flink-ml_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```